# Add alert to existing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my alert example: `alert("Limit reached");`

This is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/LRFMQ/3/

```
var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton = $("#addfield"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
{
    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><button class="removeclass">Delete</button></div>').insertBefore(InputsWrapper);          
        x++; //text box increment          
    }
    // Should I put the alert HERE ?
    return false;
});

$("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
    x--; //decrement textbox
    return false;
})
```

How can I integrate this alert into my code so that if they add too many inputs they see the alert?

I thought I had to put it between line 16 and 17 but that doesn't seem to trigger correctly.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/LRFMQ/4/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi you beat me :)

Comment: What about not using an alert and hiding the addField button?

Comment: *"but that doesn't seem to trigger correctly"* Which means what? What would be correct in this case and what happens currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
{
    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><button class="removeclass">Delete</button></div>').insertBefore(InputsWrapper);
        x++; //text box increment
    } else {
        alert("tto many inputs");
    }
    return false;
});
```

[**Your updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRFMQ/4/)

Comment: If I set max as 3 it seems to allow 4?

Answer (score 1):

You have done almost all of the work, just you need is to add an else statement:

```
if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
{
    FieldCount++; //text box added increment
    //add input box
    $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><button class="removeclass">Delete</button></div>').insertBefore(InputsWrapper);
    x++; //text box increment
} 
else 
{
    alert("Limit reached");   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle, this should be what you are looking for
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRFMQ/6/)

```
var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton = $("#addfield"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
{
    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><button class="removeclass">Delete</button></div>').insertBefore(InputsWrapper);
        x++; //text box increment
    } else {
        alert("Limit reached");
    }
    return false;
});

$("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
    x--; //decrement textbox
    return false;
})
```

Comment: It's good but again if I leave the limit as 2 then it seems to allow me to have 3 before giving me the warning. How comes?